# An error on Junos model ex3300 ( VLAN error )

Tags: juniper

I'm trying to remove a VLAN from JUNOS and then I get this error

```
error: tag value 40 is being used by more than one vlan
```

and

```
error: configuration check-out failed
```

Is there any solution ?